# How to DEBUG REDIS, APACHE issues a Docker container?

Tags: apache, debugging, docker, redis

This is the scenario:

The container comes from an image created with the follow Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5-apache


RUN apachectl -M
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod expires
RUN service apache2 restart
RUN apachectl -M

RUN php -m
RUN apt-get update
RUN php -m
RUN apt-get install -y php5-redis
RUN apt-get install -y redis-server
#RUN redis-server
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/redis.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/redis.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/redis.so
RUN php -m



COPY src/ /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80

#CMD ["redis-server"]
```

Please note the last line `CMD ["redis-server"]`.

After the image is built, I create the container like this

```
docker run -p 80:80 my_img
```

If the image is built with `#CMD ["redis-server"]` in the browser (0.0.0.0:80) I get an error message (that comes from my `index.php` file) `"Could not connetc to REDIS"`. Maybe it is because REDIS was not initialized.

If the image is build with `CMD ["redis-server"]` and that initializes REDIS (I can see the REDIS symbol in the docker terminal) but I get an error message in the browser:

[image]

So, I have no clues what is happening. I am new in Docker and have no idea how to debug it. It can be something related to the port conflicts (REDISxApache) or maybe the REDIS itself. Or that is not the way I should initialize REDIS.

Any help on that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't run dependent services in the same container. You run them as a part of compose

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build: 
      context: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  redis:
    image: redis
```

You will get the composition up using

```
$ docker-compose up
```

You will have to connect to redis at address `redis:6379` inside your php code instead of using `127.0.0.1:6379` 
For more details on docker compose refer to https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: ok @Tarun I got the idea but I am new in docker. So, Should I create a new file called docker-composer.yml and save it in the same directory of my dockerfile?  Then after run my image, I should open another terminal and run `$ docker-compose up` that will create another container...  correct?

Comment: This is what I got `docker-compose up
ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'verison' must be a mapping not a string`.

Comment: Sorry it should be `version` and not `verison`

Comment: Something with the port.  `Creating mv_php_1 ... error

ERROR: for mv_php_1  Cannot start service php: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mv_php_1 (5bb67d3448d0Creating mv_redis_1 ... done

ERROR: for php  Cannot start service php: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mv_php_1 (5bb67d3448d080bbf0b74a7a88f997189028fafcdc445aaf5c7dfcbbe6dad983): Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.` .   Maybe should I setup ServerName inside Dockerfile..

Comment: That means something is already running on port 80 of your machine

Comment: Hi what was running in my port 80 was the container created at the first `docker run -p 80:80 my_img`. If I do not run this command and just run `docker-compose up ` I will have no that above error about the port and I can see the image  of REDIS service is running, but in the other hand I still have the error in the broser ... `This page isn`t working ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155007/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-zwitterion).